# How can I add a vertical video to a vertical video frame in my website?

Tags: html, css, video, video-streaming

I want to add a video I took that is vertical in orientation to my website. I could add it to a normal horizontal video frame but then I would have an ugly black background on either side of the video. I know this is possible to do as I have seen it on this website: http://www.verticalvideos.com/index.html

What would be the best/easiest way to achieve a vertical video frame like the one in that website?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<video src="http://exit109.com/~dnn/clips/RW20seconds_1.mp4" width="360" controls=""> No video support in this browser.</video>
```

is the html5 video tag, if you want an embed from YouTube, vimeo, etc.:

```
<iframe width="400" height="700" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/tCCY31XxN_Y" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen=""></iframe>
```

for more info: [http://exit109.com/~dnn/clips/VerticalVideo.html](http://exit109.com/%7Ednn/clips/VerticalVideo.html)